# (parameter) ???: Any "???" is not accessedPylance

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, fastapi

(parameter) disease: Any
"disease" is not accessedPylance

(parameter) drug: Any
"drug" is not accessedPylance

{code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.ParameterMissing} {message: Expected parameter(s): disease, drug}

```
    def add_medicine(tx, disease, drug):
        tx.run("CREATE (m1:Medicine {disease: $disease}) "
            "CREATE (m2:Medicine {drug: $drug}) "
            "CREATE (m1)-[:TREAT]->(m2) "
            "RETURN m1, m2")
            
    with driver.session() as session:
        session.write_transaction(add_medicine,"Fever","Water")
```

Comment: What do you expect `{disease: $disease}` to do? There is nowhere you reference the `disease` variable, which is what your IDE is telling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tx.run(
   "CREATE (m1:Medicine {disease: $disease}) "
   "CREATE (m2:Medicine {drug: $drug}) "
   "CREATE (m1)-[:TREAT]->(m2) "
   "RETURN m1, m2",
   disease=disease, drug=drug)
```

Comment: To improve this and future answers, it is best to include an explanation of why your solution works, so it can aid others in the future.  Code-only answers may be downvoted. You can [edit] your post.